# Are pointers to Objective-C arrays (via a bridging header) allowed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, opengl-es

I have been trying to get the [GLCameraRipple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLCameraRipple/Introduction/Intro.html) sample from Apple running in a swift project. Unfortunately this relies heavily on using C style, thread-safe arrays only available in Objective-C.

I have been trying to use a bridging header so that the simulation can run in Objective-C code, and the drawing can run in swift code. That way the thread-safe thing would not be an issue.

I have taken the Objective-C code and translated it almost completely into swift with a few exceptions. I did cull some of the extra math since the texture is the same size as the screen for my needs. If you want to check my translation I have put them below.

Anyway I have made a class that will run in any xcode project with an opengl environment.

```
import Foundation
import GLKit
import OpenGLES

class WaterDrawer
{
    static var sim = RippleModel()
    static var shade = Shader("Shader2")

    static func pt(pt: CGPoint)
    {
        sim.initiateRippleAtLocation(pt)
    }
    static func firstStart(width: Int, height: Int)
    {
        sim.initWithScreenWidth(width / 4, iheight: height / 4, accWidth: width, accHeight: height)
        shade.begin()
        buildMatrix(width, height: height)
        bufferSetup()
    }

    static func draw()
    {
        glUseProgram(shade.progId)


        let posLoc = GLuint(glGetAttribLocation(shade.progId, "pos"))
        let texLoc = GLuint(glGetAttribLocation(shade.progId, "tc"))


        glBindBuffer(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), texVBO);
        glBufferData(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), GLsizeiptr(sim.getVertexSize()), sim.getTexCoords(), GLenum(GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW));
        glVertexAttribPointer(texLoc, 2, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0))
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(texLoc)

        glBindBuffer(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), posVBO)
        glVertexAttribPointer(posLoc, 2, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0))
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(posLoc)


        let uniOrtho = glGetUniformLocation(shade.progId, "matrix")
        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniOrtho, 1, GLboolean(GL_FALSE), &orthographicMatrix)


        glBindBuffer(GLenum(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER), indVBO)


        glDrawElements(GLenum(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP), GLsizei(sim.getIndexCount()), GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT), nil)

        glBindBuffer(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), 0)
        glBindBuffer(GLenum(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER), 0)
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(posLoc)
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(texLoc)
    }

    static func update()
    {
        sim.runSimulation()
    }


    static var posVBO:GLuint = 0
    static var texVBO:GLuint = 0
    static var indVBO:GLuint = 0
    static func bufferSetup()
    {
        Whirl.crashLog("Started passing in buffer data")

        glGenBuffers(1, &indVBO);
        glBindBuffer(GLenum(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER), indVBO);
        glBufferData(GLenum(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER), GLsizeiptr(sim.getIndexSize()), sim.getIndices(), GLenum(GL_STATIC_DRAW));

        glGenBuffers(1, &posVBO);
        glBindBuffer(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), posVBO);
        glBufferData(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), GLsizeiptr(sim.getVertexSize()), sim.getVertices(), GLenum(GL_STATIC_DRAW));


        glGenBuffers(1, &texVBO);
        glBindBuffer(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), texVBO);
        glBufferData(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), GLsizeiptr(sim.getVertexSize()), sim.getTexCoords(), GLenum(GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW));

        Whirl.crashLog("Finished passing in buffer Data")
    }


    static var orthographicMatrix:[GLfloat] = []
    static func buildMatrix(width: Int, height: Int)
    {
        orthographicMatrix = glkitmatrixtoarray(GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(0, GLfloat(width), 0, GLfloat(height), -100, 100))
        //Storage.upScaleFactor
    }
    static func glkitmatrixtoarray(mat: GLKMatrix4) -> [GLfloat]
    {
        var buildme:[GLfloat] = []
        buildme.append(mat.m.0)
        buildme.append(mat.m.1)
        buildme.append(mat.m.2)
        buildme.append(mat.m.3)
        buildme.append(mat.m.4)
        buildme.append(mat.m.5)
        buildme.append(mat.m.6)
        buildme.append(mat.m.7)
        buildme.append(mat.m.8)
        buildme.append(mat.m.9)
        buildme.append(mat.m.10)
        buildme.append(mat.m.11)
        buildme.append(mat.m.12)
        buildme.append(mat.m.13)
        buildme.append(mat.m.14)
        buildme.append(mat.m.15)
        return buildme

    }

}
```

So theoretically this code can use either the swift implementation or the Objective-C implementation, I just need to switch the way the mesh is initiated.

Trouble is when I use the Objective-C one the screen is blank, I have checked, and the buffer data looks really weird in the frame capture.

**Are you allowed to pass in data from an Objective-C code to a glBuffer?**

**Simulation.swift**

```
import Foundation
import GLKit
import OpenGLES


class RippleModel
{
    var screenWidth:UInt32 = 0
    var screenHeight:UInt32 = 0
    var poolWidth:UInt32 = 0
    var poolHeight:UInt32 = 0
    var screenWidthi:Int = 0
    var screenHeighti:Int = 0
    var poolWidthi:Int = 0
    var poolHeighti:Int = 0

    let touchRadius:Int = 5 //5 i think

    var rippleVertices:[GLfloat] = []
    var rippleTexCoords:[GLfloat] = []
    var rippleIndices:[GLushort] = []//NOTE IF CHANGE THIS TO INTO SO MUCH DRAW CALL

    var rippleSource:[GLfloat] = []
    var rippleDest:[GLfloat] = []

    var rippleCoeff:[GLfloat] = []


    var VertexSize:GLsizeiptr = 0
    var IndicieSize:GLsizeiptr = 0
    var IndicieCount:Int = 0

    func calculateSizes()
    {
        VertexSize = rippleVertices.count * sizeof(GLfloat)
        IndicieSize = rippleIndices.count * sizeof(GLushort)
        IndicieCount = rippleIndices.count

        Whirl.crashLog("Data sizes Vertex size \(VertexSize)\tIndicie Size \(IndicieSize) \tIndicie Count \(IndicieCount)")
    }
    func figureOutCoefficent()
    {
        for y in 0...(2 * touchRadius)
        {
            for x in 0...(2 * touchRadius)
            {
                let dx = x - touchRadius
                let dy = y - touchRadius
                let distance = sqrt(GLfloat(dx * dx + dy * dy))

                let me = y * (touchRadius*2 + 1) + x
                if (distance <= GLfloat(touchRadius))
                {
                    let factor = distance / GLfloat(touchRadius)
                    rippleCoeff[me] = -(cos(factor*GLfloat(M_PI))+1.0) * 256.0;
                }
                else
                {
                    rippleCoeff[me] = 0.0
                }
            }
        }

    }
    init()
    {

    }
    func initWithScreenWidth( iwidth: Int,  iheight: Int, accWidth: Int, accHeight: Int)
    {
        screenWidth = UInt32(accWidth);screenWidthi = Int(screenWidth)
        screenHeight = UInt32(accHeight);screenHeighti = Int(screenHeight)

        poolWidth = UInt32(iwidth);poolWidthi = Int(poolWidth)
        poolHeight = UInt32(iheight);poolHeighti = Int(poolHeight)


        //WE DONT NEED TEX COORD MUMBO JUMBO IT IS FULL SCREEN ALREADY
        Whirl.crashLog("Started allocation")

        rippleCoeff = [GLfloat](count: Int( (touchRadius * 2 + 1) * (touchRadius*2 + 1) ), repeatedValue: 0)
        figureOutCoefficent()

        let simCount:Int = Int(poolWidth + 2) * Int(poolHeight + 2)
        rippleSource = [GLfloat](count: simCount, repeatedValue: 0)
        rippleDest = [GLfloat](count: simCount, repeatedValue: 0)

        let locb:Int = Int(poolWidth * poolHeight * 2)
        rippleVertices = [GLfloat](count: locb, repeatedValue: 0)
        rippleTexCoords = [GLfloat](count: locb, repeatedValue: 0)

        rippleIndices = [GLushort](count: Int(poolHeight - 1) * Int((poolWidth * 2) + 2), repeatedValue: 0)

        Whirl.crashLog("Finished allocation")

        initMesh()

        calculateSizes()
    }
    func initMesh()
    {
        Whirl.crashLog("Started initting pos coords")

        for i in 0..<poolHeight
        {let ii = GLfloat(i)
            for j in 0..<poolWidth
            {let jj = GLfloat(j)
                let cordb:Int = Int(i*poolWidth+j)*2


                rippleVertices[cordb + 0] = (jj / GLfloat(poolWidth - 1)) * GLfloat(screenWidth)
                rippleVertices[cordb + 1] = (ii / GLfloat(poolHeight - 1)) * GLfloat(screenHeight)


                rippleTexCoords[cordb + 0] = ii / GLfloat(poolHeight - 1)
                rippleTexCoords[cordb + 1] = (jj/GLfloat(poolWidth - 1))

            }
        }

        Whirl.crashLog("Finished initting pos coords")

        Whirl.crashLog("Started initting index coords")

        var index = 0
        for i in 0 ..< poolHeighti-1
        {
            for j in 0 ..< poolWidthi
            {
                if (i%2 == 0)
                {
                    // emit extra index to create degenerate triangle
                    if (j == 0)
                    {
                        rippleIndices[index] = GLushort(i*poolWidthi+j);
                        index += 1;
                    }

                    rippleIndices[index] = GLushort(i*poolWidthi+j);
                    index += 1;
                    rippleIndices[index] = GLushort((i+1)*poolWidthi+j);
                    index += 1;

                    // emit extra index to create degenerate triangle
                    if (j == (poolWidthi-1))
                    {
                        rippleIndices[index] = GLushort((i+1)*poolWidthi+j);
                        index += 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // emit extra index to create degenerate triangle
                    if (j == 0)
                    {
                        rippleIndices[index] = GLushort((i+1)*poolWidthi+j);
                        index += 1;
                    }

                    rippleIndices[index] = GLushort((i+1)*poolWidthi+j);
                    index += 1;
                    rippleIndices[index] = GLushort(i * poolWidthi + j);
                    index += 1;

                    // emit extra index to create degenerate triangle
                    if (j == (poolWidthi-1))
                    {
                        rippleIndices[index] = GLushort(i * poolWidthi + j);
                        index += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        Whirl.crashLog("Finished initting coords")
    }

    var firstUpdate = true
    func runSimulation()
    {
        if (firstUpdate)
        {firstUpdate = false; Whirl.crashLog("First update")}

        let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

        //dispatch_apply(Int(poolHeight), queue, {(y: size_t) -> Void in
        for y in 0..<poolHeighti {
            let pw = self.poolWidthi
            for x in 1..<(pw - 1)
            {
                let ai:Int = (y    ) * (pw + 2) + x + 1
                let bi:Int = (y + 2) * (pw + 2) + x + 1
                let ci:Int = (y + 1) * (pw + 2) + x
                let di:Int = (y + 1) * (pw + 2) + x + 2
                let me:Int = (y + 1) * (pw + 2) + x + 1

                let a = self.rippleSource[ai]
                let b = self.rippleSource[bi]
                let c = self.rippleSource[ci]
                let d = self.rippleSource[di]

                var result = (a + b + c + d) / 2.0 - self.rippleDest[me]
                result -= result / 32.0

                self.rippleDest[me] = result
            }
        }
        //)


        let hm1 = GLfloat(poolHeight - 1)
        let wm1 = GLfloat(poolWidth - 1)
        //dispatch_apply(poolHeighti, queue, {(y: size_t) -> Void in
        for y in 0..<poolHeighti{
            let yy = GLfloat(y)
            let pw = self.poolWidthi
            for x in 1..<(pw - 1)
            {let xx = GLfloat(x)
                let ai:Int = (y    ) * (pw + 2) + x + 1
                let bi:Int = (y + 2) * (pw + 2) + x + 1
                let ci:Int = (y + 1) * (pw + 2) + x
                let di:Int = (y + 1) * (pw + 2) + x + 2

                let a = self.rippleDest[ai]
                let b = self.rippleDest[bi]
                let c = self.rippleDest[ci]
                let d = self.rippleDest[di]

                var s_offset = ((b - a) / 2048)
                var t_offset = ((c - d) / 2048)

                s_offset = (s_offset < -0.5) ? -0.5 : s_offset;
                t_offset = (t_offset < -0.5) ? -0.5 : t_offset;
                s_offset = (s_offset >  0.5) ?  0.5 : s_offset;
                t_offset = (t_offset >  0.5) ?  0.5 : t_offset;

                let s_tc = yy / hm1
                let t_tc = xx / wm1

                let me = (y * pw + x) * 2
                self.rippleTexCoords[me + 0] = s_tc + s_offset
                self.rippleTexCoords[me + 1] = t_tc + t_offset

            }
        }
        //)

        let pTmp = rippleDest
        rippleDest = rippleSource
        rippleSource = pTmp
    }

    var firstRipple:Bool = true
    func initiateRippleAtLocation(location: CGPoint)
    {
        if (firstRipple)
        {firstRipple = false; Whirl.crashLog("First ripple placement")}

        let xIndex = Int((GLfloat(location.x) / GLfloat(screenWidth)) * GLfloat(poolWidthi))
        let yIndex = Int((1.0 - (GLfloat(location.y) / GLfloat(screenHeighti))) * GLfloat(poolHeight))

        let lowy = yIndex - touchRadius
        let highy = yIndex + touchRadius
        let lowx = xIndex - touchRadius
        let highx = xIndex + touchRadius


        //Whirl.crashLog("Ripple at (\(xIndex) , \(yIndex))\tX:(\(lowx) - \(highx))\tY:(\(lowy) - \(highy))")

        for y in lowy...highy
        {
            for x in lowx...highx
            {
                if (x > 0 && x < (poolWidthi - 1) && y > 0 && y < poolHeighti)
                {
                    let ind = (poolWidthi + 2) * (y + 1) + x + 1
                    let coef = (y-(yIndex-touchRadius))*(touchRadius*2+1)+x-(xIndex-touchRadius)
                    let past = rippleSource[ind]
                    let coe = rippleCoeff[coef]
                    if (coe < past)
                    {
                        rippleSource[ind] = coe
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    func rippleLine(location1: CGPoint, location2: CGPoint)
    {
        if (firstRipple)
        {firstRipple = false; Whirl.crashLog("First ripple placement")}

        let xIndex1 = Int((GLfloat(location1.x) / GLfloat(screenWidth)) * GLfloat(poolWidthi))
        let yIndex1 = Int((1.0 - (GLfloat(location1.y) / GLfloat(screenHeighti))) * GLfloat(poolHeight))
        let xIndex2 = Int((GLfloat(location2.x) / GLfloat(screenWidth)) * GLfloat(poolWidthi))
        let yIndex2 = Int((1.0 - (GLfloat(location2.y) / GLfloat(screenHeighti))) * GLfloat(poolHeight))

        let lowy1 = yIndex1 - touchRadius
        let highy1 = yIndex1 + touchRadius
        let lowx1 = xIndex1 - touchRadius
        let highx1 = xIndex1 + touchRadius

        let lowy2 = yIndex2 - touchRadius
        let highy2 = yIndex2 + touchRadius
        let lowx2 = xIndex2 - touchRadius
        let highx2 = xIndex2 + touchRadius

        let lowx = min(lowx1, lowx2)
        let highx = max(highx1, highx2)
        let lowy = min(lowy1, lowy2)
        let highy = max(highy1, highy2)

        for y in lowy...highy
        {
            for x in lowx...highx
            {
                if (x > 0 && x < (poolWidthi - 1) && y > 0 && y < poolHeighti)
                {
                    let ind = (poolWidthi + 2) * (y + 1) + x + 1

                    let tar = ldist(CGPoint(x: xIndex1, y: yIndex1), p2: CGPoint(x: xIndex2, y: yIndex2), me: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))

                    let dx = x - Int(tar.x)
                    let dy = y - Int(tar.y)
                    let distq = (dx * dx + dy * dy)

                    if (distq < touchRadius * touchRadius)
                    {
                        let factor = sqrt(GLfloat(distq)) / GLfloat(touchRadius)

                        rippleSource[ind] = -(cos(factor*GLfloat(M_PI))+1.0) * 256.0;
                    }
                    //rippleSource[ind] = 1000
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func ldist(p1: CGPoint, p2: CGPoint, me: CGPoint) -> CGPoint
    {
        let diffX = p2.x - p1.x
        let diffY = p2.y - p1.y

        var target = CGPoint()
        if ((diffX == 0) && (diffY == 0))
        {
            target = p1
        }

        let t = ((me.x - p1.x) * diffX + (me.y - p1.y) * diffY) / (diffX * diffX + diffY * diffY)

        if (t < 0)
        {
            target = p1
        }
        else if (t > 1)
        {
            target = p2
        }
        else
        {
            target = CGPoint(x: (p1.x + t * diffX), y: (p1.y + t * diffY))
        }

        let int = CGPoint(x: round(target.x), y: round(target.y))
        return int
    }

    func getVertices() -> [GLfloat]
    {
        //Return the mesh positions
        return rippleVertices
    }
    func getTexCoords() -> [GLfloat]
    {
        //Return the array of texture coords
        return rippleTexCoords
    }
    func getIndices() -> [GLushort]
    {
        //Return the array of indices
        return rippleIndices
    }
    func getVertexSize() -> GLsizeiptr
    {
        //Return the size of the mesh position array
        return VertexSize
    }
    func getIndexSize() -> GLsizeiptr
    {
        //Return the byte size of the incicie array
        return IndicieSize
    }
    func getIndexCount() -> GLsizeiptr
    {
        //This goes in the draw call, count of indices
        return IndicieCount
    }
}
```

**[RippleModel.m (from apple)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLCameraRipple/Listings/GLCameraRipple_RippleModel_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011222-GLCameraRipple_RippleModel_m-DontLinkElementID_6)**

Comment: I don't believe in passing swift datatype to gl function. I think you need to convert the datatype to byte array or c-style format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are you allowed to pass in data from an objective-c code to a glBuffer?

Why wouldn't you be allowed?  Swift has a pointer API (`UnsafePointer<T>`, `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>`, etc.) exactly for this purpose.  Obviously this is "unsafe" in the sense that the underlying memory the [Objective-]C pointer points to could change at anytime without the Swift pointer knowing.  It also has no information about the size of the memory block that it points to.

Any C pointers or arrays can be bridged to Swift (probably as `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>` which you will need to cast to your OpenGL type).

You can avoid any risk of referencing invalid memory by dereferencing the pointer (if it is non-nil) and copying the value stored at the pointer to a variable in your Swift application.

Answer (score 1):

With OpenGL ES being a pure set of C functions, I don't think passing a pointer of swift datatypes will work easily.

The following code will give you a hint of how to pass the index buffer.

```
var Indices: [GLubyte] = [
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0
]

var indexBuffer: GLuint = GLuint()
glGenBuffers(1, &indexBuffer)
glBindBuffer(GLenum(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER), indexBuffer)
glBufferData(GLenum(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER), Indices.size(), Indices, GLenum(GL_STATIC_DRAW))
```

Reference: Here is a link with a working code. https://github.com/bradley/iOSSwiftOpenGL/blob/master/iOSSwiftOpenGL/OpenGLView.swift